# Shopify Filter with Multiple Tags at Once, in Two Groups

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have multiple products organized with tags and the tags repeat across multiple products. The organization is set up like this:

Home Products

-tag1

-tag2

-tag3

Outdoor Products

-tag4

-tag5

-tag6

And the Liquid, like this:

```
<div class="home-products">
{% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
    {% assign tag_handle = tag | handle %}
    {% if tag_handle contains 'tag1' or tag_handle contains 'tag2' or tag_handle contains 'tag3' %}
        {% if current_tags contains tag %}
            <div class="tag--active">
                {% if tag_handle contains 'tag1' %}               
                    {{ tag | link_to_remove_tag: tag }}     
                {% elsif tag_handle contains 'tag2' %}                
                    {{ tag | link_to_remove_tag: tag }}     
                {% elsif tag_handle contains 'tag3' %}                
                    {{ tag | link_to_remove_tag: tag }} 
                {% endif %}             
            </div>
            {% else %}
            <div>
                {% comment %}
                    Use link_to_add_tag if you want to allow filtering
                    by multiple tags
                {% endcomment %}
                {% if tag_handle contains 'tag1' %}               
                    {{ tag | link_to_add_tag: tag }}    
                {% elsif tag_handle contains 'tag2' %}                
                    {{ tag | link_to_add_tag: tag }}    
                {% elsif tag_handle contains 'tag3' %}                
                    {{ tag | link_to_add_tag: tag }} 
                {% endif %} 
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>

<div class="personal-care-products">
{% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
    {% assign tag_handle = tag | handle %}
    {% if tag_handle contains 'tag4' or tag_handle contains 'tag5' or tag_handle contains 'tag6' %}
        {% if current_tags contains tag %}
            <div class="tag--active">
                {% if tag_handle contains 'tag4' %}               
                    {{ tag | link_to_remove_tag: tag }}     
                {% elsif tag_handle contains 'tag5' %}                
                    {{ tag | link_to_remove_tag: tag }}     
                {% elsif tag_handle contains 'tag6' %}                
                    {{ tag | link_to_remove_tag: tag }} 
                {% endif %}             
            </div>
            {% else %}
            <div>
                {% comment %}
                    Use link_to_add_tag if you want to allow filtering
                    by multiple tags
                {% endcomment %}
                {% if tag_handle contains 'tag4' %}               
                    {{ tag | link_to_add_tag: tag }}    
                {% elsif tag_handle contains 'tag5' %}                
                    {{ tag | link_to_add_tag: tag }}    
                {% elsif tag_handle contains 'tag6' %}                
                    {{ tag | link_to_add_tag: tag }} 
                {% endif %} 
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

My problem is that I want it to "reset" each time you switch between categories.  Currently, if you click on a couple from on section, then one from the next, you get

collections/all/tag1+tag2+tag5

when it should be

collections/all/tag5

Thoughts?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your second loop is using the `collection.all_tags` array modified by the first loop. Instead, create a copy of the tags. Try this:

```
{% assign newArray = "" | split: ""  %}
{% assign tags = newArray | concat : collection.all_tags %}

{% for tag in tags %}
   ...Home Products...
{% endfor %}

{% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
   ...Outdoor Products...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I gave it a shot and it's still not working as it still treats both groups as one.  When I click on a tag from group 2, it doesn't clear and "start over" like I want it to.

Comment: yeah, looks like `link_to_add_tag` uses a global array internally.

Comment: Bummer.  Do you think there's another way to do it?